# d3.js pan restricted behaviour

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a basic linear chart with pan/zoom functionality

I managed to get the zoom to work as I want it, but when i try to pan, it only moves diagonally and i'm not really sure why.

Here is my zoom function

```
function zoomed() {
  var transform = d3.event.transform;
  var updatedxScale = transform.rescaleX(xScale);
  var updatedyScale = transform.rescaleX(yScale);

  d3.select("zoom-base").attr("transform", transform);
  gX.call(xAxis.scale(updatedxScale));
  gY.call(yAxis.scale(updatedyScale));

  line.x((d, i) => updatedxScale(i)).y(d => updatedyScale(d));
  gPath.attr("d", line);
}
```

Here is the example for better context https://jsfiddle.net/kaisk/zp5qesL4/

Any ideas on how to make it pan freely with no restrictions?

Comment: don't change the `.x()` and `.y()` of the line, the transform will take care of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with your code.

- don't change the line in the `zoomed` function
- use `rescaleY` for the y-axis
- add the line to a separate `g` and apply the zoom transform to this `g`

Here a refactored version but you need to add a clip region yourself. Enough examples here on SO.

```js
var dataset = ["0.47122", "0.22919", "0.11264", "0.36817", "0.95380", "0.99119", "0.44896", "0.24597", "0.35834", "0.83772", "0.25262", "0.87030", "0.71527", "0.12048", "0.87286", "0.62833", "0.79057", "0.75939", "0.43300", "0.98306", "0.72953"];

var margin = {
  top: 10,
  right: 10,
  bottom: 25,
  left: 25
};

var svgWidth = 600;
var svgHeight = 350;
var width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, dataset.length - 1])
  .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 1])
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

var line = d3.line()
  .x((d, i) => xScale(i))
  .y(d => yScale(d))
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([0.8, 2])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

var gY = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

var gline = svg.append('g');

var gPath = gline.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line(dataset));

d3.select('svg').call(zoom);

function zoomed() {
  var transform = d3.event.transform;
  var updatedxScale = transform.rescaleX(xScale);
  var updatedyScale = transform.rescaleY(yScale);

  gPath.attr("transform", transform);
  gX.call(xAxis.scale(updatedxScale));
  gY.call(yAxis.scale(updatedyScale));
}
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #4286f4;
  stroke-width: 3;
}

.dot {
  fill: #4286f4;
  stroke: #fff;
}

.view {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="chart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man! That helped alot, I fixed the issues and the clip path made it confined inside the graph area! Here is the [updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/kaisk/zp5qesL4/30/)